# Control AVAudioPlayer via Apple iPhone Earpods

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, avaudioplayer

Im using `AVAudioPlayer` to play audio files in audiobook application. How can i solve problem of unsupported earpods control actions?

For example, when i double press home button and player controls shown on screen (◄◄, ►, ►► for rewind/play/forward) - this buttons are not responding on pressing. Earpods joystick dont work too (except volume control), I mean joystick middle button usage to control playback/pause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with a call to -[UIApplication beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents]. The rest of what you need is in the UIResponder class.